UKI Triggers "Overlapping PE sections detected" Warning on Boot
I recently installed Debian 12 on three separate old laptops.
I created a unified kernel image for each (both to learn and to speed up boot).
I used systemd-ukify, following the instructions here.
Everything works and I am able to boot without a bootloader.
However, on all three instances I get a red text shown during the manufacturer logo/splash screen, saying Overlapping PE sections detected. Boot may fail due to image corruption.
Now, as the images boot fine, I cannot figure out what is wrong or how to remove this warning.
Isn't ukify meant to automatically calculate the correct section offsets?
I also don't know if the few seconds spent showing this warning is pointlessly slowing down the boot process.
